# Display table not rendering the data on jsp page

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I am using the display table to show the data in the listing form on the jsp` page.
I creating list in my struts2 action class and forward it on the jsp page.it works fine for multiple time,but some time it not render the data in the display table(shows the message on top of the table 'XX no of records found display XX no of records').

Here is my jsp code :-

```
 <display:table name="UserList" requestURI="" id="user"
        pagesize="${myPageSize}" class="listingTable" keepStatus="true">
        <display:column title="Name" >
                <a href="javascript:onclick=showDetails(${user.id})">
                        <c:out value="${user.name}" escapeXml="false"></c:out>
                </a>
        </display:column>

        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.item_name" value="User" />
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.items_name" value="User" />

</display:table>
```

Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you did not get data in display table. Pls. check whether your list return data in action file or not. Because code seems ok in jsp side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jwalin,my class returns the data every time,i print the data inside the class before returning to jsp page.As well on the top of the display table this message is also prints :'10 Users found, displaying all Users'.